# Change Thread Session ID

Tags: windows, multithreading, session, service, windows-vista

How could I start a thread in a different session? I need to start a thread in the interactive session (session 1) from a service in the non-interactive session (session 0). I have done this with a process before by using SetTokenInFormation and DuplicateTokenEx and then passing this to CreateProcessAsUser. I was hoping I could do the same thing except use SetThreadToken instead of CreateProcessAsUser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Threads don't belong to sessions, processes do.  You'll need to create a process in the other session to host the thread you want.